Multidimensional Sample Tool not working on ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro
I have several .crf files (Multidimensional Raster) on a specific dataset.
I designed the model below to extract a sample from each of the files to a table based on a specific polygon.
When the tool "Sample" is opened on a standalone session it identifies the multidimensional input and enables the checkbox so I can choose that I want a multidimensional output. However when I'm inside the ModelBuilder environment the tool doesn't "know" that I want to work with multidimensional data so the checkbox remain disabled.
Does anyone have a suggestion for a workaround?
The first image is the MB structure, the second is the Sample tool when opened inside the MB and the third is the Sample tool opened from Geoprocessing tab.

Sample Tool Without Multidimensional Checkbox opened in MB

Sample Tool With Multidimensional Checkbox opened as standalone


I too can replicate the issue in Modelbuilder. The help files states for the raster layer parameter:

The process_as_multidimensional parameter is only supported when the
input is a single, multidimensional raster.

Your model implies it is getting a dataset (so no necessarily a CRF file) or the CRF is not what you think it is. I think more research of this Multidimensional raster data page might help you.
